# Create WFS with Mapguide Studio Enterprise 2011

Tags: wfs, mapguide

i need create a WFS with MGS 2011, i used the help users mapguide for create the WFS but that didnt work, can anyone help me please?
i am new in this tecnology.

Comment: Mapguide won't create the wfs. Mapguide will server it. I believe you need studio or autocad map to create/publish the service. http://www.gis-services.sk/files/File/download%20pdf/Autodesk_Infrastructure_Map_Server_2012_Overview_Scripted_Demo.pdf

Comment: Thanks so much, but in [link]( images.autodesk.com/adsk/files/studiousersguide.pdf) page 67 explain how to do for publish wfs, but that doesnt work. I use mapguide studio enterprise 2011. I think that something is fail me... any suggestion?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have ent I have used mgos and map but not to create a wfs service. Edit your question with more information about why it fails. Maybe someone else will help.